# The set of all vectors satisfying $Ax\ge\vec{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, linear-programming, dual-cone

Consider a rectangle matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ with $m\ge n$, and the set of all vectors $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying $Ax\ge\vec{0}$. I note this set is closed under multiplication by a scalar and linear combinations with positive coefficients.

Can one define for it the analogue of a basis of linear sub-space? Is there some notion of well-defined dimension for such a set?

EDITED: Thanks to @AlgebraicPavel we know it is a convex cone, or the dual cone of A.

Comment: What is your definition of $\ge$?

Comment: The set you describe is a cone. You can read more about it and related matrix results, e.g., [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=TaXiBQAAQBAJ).

Comment: The definition of $Ax\ge0$ is $\forall i=1..N, (Ax)_i\ge0$